# CSS, outgoing menu with the right side

Tags: css, menu

How to make a menu when you leave can only hide after clicking the cross? Because now is that when u open menu u can click anywhere and he will hide out.

https://jsfiddle.net/fm7ayygc/

```
<nav class="site-nav">
    <button class="side-menu-trigger"><span class="glyphicon" style=" font-size: 10px; margin-right: 3px;">&#xe234;
    </span>Pokaż menu</button>
    <aside class="side-menu">
      <div class="row center-block">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <h4>Menu</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </aside>
  </nav>
```

CSS

```
.site-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
 }

.side-menu-trigger { 
  margin-top: 90px; 
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #0079BF;
  border: 0;
  text-decoration: underline;
  }

.side-menu { 
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  top: 40px;
  right: -300px;
  padding: 0;
  background: #EDEFF0;
  transition: 0.3s transform ease-in-out; 

  }

.side-menu-trigger:focus ~ .side-menu, .side-menu:hover {
  transform: translateX(-300px); 

  }
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly your issue you are having is?

Comment: When u open menu, and click anywhere u want beyond the menu, he will hide out, i wont it, I need to disappear only when I want, when I click on the cross

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the functionality you want with just CSS, you will need JavaScript. Consider the code below as an option to open and close your menu. Keep in mind this is a simple `display` toggle and will not slide the way you have it now. I'll leave the animation research to you.

```
var menu = document.getElementById('side-menu');
var menuLink = document.getElementById('side-menu-trigger');

menuLink.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (menu.style.display=="block") {
    menu.style.display="none";
  } else {
    menu.style.display="block";
  }
});
```